# UITextView height 0 inside of StackView after disabling scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have three child VCs that are added to a parent VC. In one of my child VC, I have a view being loaded from a nib. In that nib, I set up a `UITextView` with no constraints and disabled scrolling so that it dynamically sizes depending on the text. This all works fine so far, I can enter or remove text from the `UITextView` and it resizes accordingly.

However, if I switch tabs (child VCs), and return back to the one with my `UITextView`, my `UITextView` is now of height 0 (cannot be seen). I'm not sure what is causing this to happen, everything works fine until I switch views and return.

My first thought would be to reconfigure my `UITextView` on `viewDidAppear()` when returning to my child VC, except my `UITextView` outlet and setup method is in a separate `UIView` subclass so I cannot call `viewDidAppear()`. I'm not even sure if that would be a fix, just what I would guess.

```
MyParent.swift: UIViewController
   MyChild1.swift: UIViewController
   MyChild2.swift: UIViewController
   MyChild3.swift: UIViewController
      MyView.swift: UIView - Custom View loaded from Nib
      (this is where my UITextView outlet is and setup for it)
```

In MyChild3 for example I create the custom view with:

```
let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first! as! MyView
view.myModel = model
view.configure()
```

Then, in MyView.swift which is the custom class that the nib uses, I have my `UITextView` outlet and setup method:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

public func configure() {
    configureTextView()
}

private func configureTextView() {
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.text = myModel.text
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

EDIT:

I should mention that my UITextView is a part of a horizontal StackView along with a UIImageView, as follows:

```
UIImageView
UITextView
```

When I return to my VC, the UIImageView takes up 100% of the height in the StackView, although before leaving my VC, the UITextView height was sized correctly to its text. After doing Show View Hierarchy, I cannot even find my UITextView anymore, only the UIImageView seems to be in the StackView. I essentially want my UITextView to take up as much height as it needs in the StackView, and the UIImageView take up the rest, but the UIImageView is taking it all up.

I did manage to find this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting content compression resistance of the `textView` to a higher value, maybe that's what causing ambiguity:

```
textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999), for: .vertical)
```